# Enabling social customer service in Developer Edition

Tags: servicecloud

I am trying to evaluate Social Customer Service and wanted some hands on. I have created a new Developer Edition account today and from [this link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=social_customer_service_setup.htm&language=en_US) I can head straight into the Social Media section:

> If your organization was created during the Spring '16 release or later, you do not need to contact Salesforce first. Go directly to the Social Media section of the Setup menu to find Social Customer Service settings.

I can see the "Enable Social Accounts, Contacts, and Leads" option and have selected and saved it. But nothing seems to be happening. There is alink for a video on "Enabling Social Customer Service" and it refers to an option "Social Apps Integration" under "Customize".

As I'm on a Developer Edition, I can't log a case to enable this.

Anyone else facing the same problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Rohit,

Salesforce will not enable these features on Developer orgs as Radian6 is only available as a paid for product with no equivalent for Dev orgs. The free listeners for two social accounts on paid Salesforce orgs are not available for Developer orgs I suspect because of the cost of providing social media listening services.